# Dynamic Django Model Control

Tags: django

I am designing a quiz engine by using django.
In the models.py, I have such classes:

```
class Quiz (models.Model):
    quiz_id = models.AutoField (primary_key=True)
    problem_desc = models.TextField (blank=True)
    problem_has_resource = models.BoolField ()
    problem_is_choice = models.BooleanField ()
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.quiz_id

class Choice (models.Model):
    choice_id = models.AutoField (primary_key=True)
    quiz_id = models.ForeignKey (Quiz);
    choice_desc = models.CharField (max_length = 500)
    is_answer = models.BooleanField ()

class Answer (models.Model):
    quiz_id = models.ForeignKey (Quiz)
    input_answer = models.FloatField ()

class Quiz_Resource (models.Model):
    quiz_id = models.ForeignKey (Quiz)
    title = form.CharField (max_length = 50)
    file = forms.FileField ()
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.file.name
```

A quiz may need to be inputted an "Answer" or chosen a choice. A quiz may have many choices. A quiz may have some extra resource. I want  the boolfield to control the admin page style, set formal info. How can I achieve it?

Bow, thanks!

enter code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to relate your quiz model to your Choice, Answer and Quiz_Ressource models.

```
class Quiz (models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    problem_desc = models.TextField (blank=True)
    problem_has_resource = models.BoolField ()
    problem_is_choice = models.BooleanField ()

    choices=models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
    answers=models.ManyToManyField(Answer)
    ressources=models.ManyToManyField(Quiz_Ressource)
```

That way you tell Django that your Quiz model references to multiple models of the type Choice, Answer and Quiz_Ressource. You can search for the concept of ManyToMany in relational databases if this is unclear.

After you have rewritten your model like that, there will be fields for adding and selecting choices, anwers and ressources on the admin pages.

To continue along with django use the documentation as provided here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships

Your needs for custom admin templates is a different story. You can do that with something like this in your apps admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from yourapp.models import Quiz

class QuizAdminSite(AdminSite):

    def admin_quiz(request):
        #here goes your custom admin view code, where you can do
        #if has_ressource: return render_to_response('admin/quiz/has_ressource.html')
        #elif is_choice: return render_to_response('admin/quiz/is_choice.html')
        #and so on, you have to work out yourself how this has to look exactly
        return HttpResponse('your custom admin view')

    def get_urls(self):
    from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
    urls = super(ItemAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('',
        url(
            r'update_feeds',
            self.admin_site.admin_view(self.admin_quiz),
            name='admin_quiz',
        ),
    )
    return my_urls + urls    


class QuizAdmin(QuizAdminSite):
    model=Quiz

admin.site.register(Quiz,QuizAdmin)
```

I don't know exactly what you want to do with your custom admin view, so i skipped that part. But that should be the path to follow.

Comment: Thanks! Now I want to design a special web page to work as a admin page